# why __gc didn't work when collecting garbage for table？

Tags: lua

Recently, I was learning about garbage collection. I have coded an example. The code is as follows:

```
mytablea {"1","2","3"}
print(collectgarbage("count"))
for i = 1, 500000 do
    table.insert(mytable, i)
end
debug.setmetatable(mytable, {_gc = function ()print("dead")end})
mytable = nil
print(collectgarbage("count"))
print(collectgarbage("collect"))
print(collectgarbage("count"))
```

I'm confused about why there is no output in my terminal (__gc doesn't seem to work). But after finishing the call `collectgarbage`, its memory does decrease! I wonder if lua 5.1 didn't support this on table or if something is wrong with my linux (maybe some bug in my ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

The correct metatable entry is `__gc`, not `_gc`.

In any case, Lua 5.1 does not support gc metamethods for tables.

Comment: Oh! The document did really no mention of  table! Thanks, i should have read the document carefully!

Comment: _Garbage collection metatable entry_ is such a thing: Lua 5.1 just supports it for **userdata**, LuaJIT has [ffi.gc](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_api.html) for **cdata**, with Lua 5.2 came it for **tables**. All 3 versions are actively used.

Answer (score 1):

Lua 5.1 does not support `__gc` (note, it's two underscores, not one) on tables.
If possible move to a newer version of Lua (i.e. 5.2 or 5.3) to get support.

If you really need it; you can use the undocumented `newproxy` function to get a userdata to attach a `__gc` to instead:

```
do
    local p = newproxy(false);
    debug.setmetatable(p, {__gc = function() print("dead") end})
    local t = {some_key = p}
end
collectgarbage()
collectgarbage()
```

I use this in projects where I need lua 5.1 compatibility, e.g. https://github.com/wahern/cqueues/blob/3f2fc57a07bb9e658f4d53ccc60ba8177e3f1236/src/dns.resolvers.lua#L53